# Problems to run kernel with Virtual OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am trying to run some kernels with virtual OpenCL (http://www.mosix.org/txt_vcl.html)

When I query the devices I see 3 CPUs and 2 GPUs (got 3 computers with virtual OpenCL, two with AMD APUs and one with an Intel CPU)

When I try to copy data and run a kernel, the Intel CPU works fine (if host ore remote doesn't matter). The other devices either do not run the kernel or bring errors like CL_INVALID_CONTEXT, CL_INVALID_KERNEL or CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT.

The same code executed on each of the machines without virtual OpenCL works totally fine.
Any idea?

Comment: BTW: I have an AMD E-350, an AMD A10-5800K and an Intel Core2 Duo U9600. All on Ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: clGetDeviceInfo works fine, just writting buffers and executing kernels makes problems. Most time the intel cpu device works, but the others don't. I have tried AMD Catalyst driver 9.1.11 (beta) and 8.98.2.

Answer (score 0):

I got some feedback from the VCL team.

My problem is a known bug with the AMD OpenCL SDK and VCL. There are problems to support AMDs OpenCL 1.2. They recently released VCL 1.7 to work around the problem. Unfortunately this didn't work for me.

Another tip was to go back to OpenCL 1.1. So I installed AMD APP 2.5 and VCL 1.7 and at least the CPU works remote now. I will try AMD APP 2.6 and 2.7 next to see if I get the GPU to work as well.

If anyone has a better idea, please post.